# How do I access the HTTP request from a custom Ambient processor?

Tags: 2013-sp1, ambient-data-framework

I'm writing a custom ClaimProcessor for the Ambient Data Framework. I need to access some HTTP request headers to make it work.
How do I access the HTTP request from my claim processor? Or at least, how do I get to the request headers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot access the request object directly, as cartridges are web-application-agnostic (i.e. the .NET request object is very different from the JSP one). Instead, you can access the headers and other parameters from the ClaimStore passed into your methods.

The ADF automatically extracts the variables from the request and adds them as claims. For a list of the predefined claims, take a look at the [Default Claims](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-66EDBEF0-FA3D-4B40-A8DB-7A2C7789C903) page of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I couldn't find the URIs for these default claims (which would have been rather useful) so I wrote them up myself: http://blog.trivident.com/claim-names-and-uris/.